# Anyone know how to make 2D riggs in blender?

Tags: rigging, 2d

I know its possible and ive seen it done but I can't for the life of me find a guide on how to do it.

Im currently using the 2.8 beta I just need a way to switch between body parts like an open hand and closed hand or head turn arounds and how to rig bones to a grease pencil drawing

Comment: Use drivers to drive the *Render Visibility*. That way the position of a bone can influence the Render Visibility (and/or Viewport Vis) of multiple image planes.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by this

Comment: Can you clarify? Are there certain words you don't understand? Is it the context?

Comment: Its just ive only been using blender for a few months so I get what you're telling me in to do in context I just don't fully understand how to do it. Like I don't know how to set any of that up. Ive been googleing the terms you used but nothing helpful comes up

Comment: Do you know how to "rig"? Do you know how to use the armature with an armature modifier and meshes? Have you learned how to setup up drivers? These are all essential prerequisites, which should be learned beforehand. If you don't know how to use any of these tools, an answer would be a lengthy tutorial, which is not in the scope of [blender.se].se.